# Is there an equivalent of the Devise helper `sign_in` that I can use in a Capybara feature test?

Tags: authentication, capybara, integration-testing

I am trying to write a feature test for a resource which would only be available to a signed in user, is there an equivalent helpr method to devise's `sign_in' that I can use, or do I have to take Capybara manually through the signin in process?

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative '../support/new_quote_form'

feature 'creating quote request' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:new_quote_form) { NewQuoteForm.new }

    before do
        sign_in(user) #Would be nice and easy!
    end

    scenario 'completing quote data' do
        new_quote_form.visit_page.fill_in_with().submit
        expect(page).to have_content('Quote request created')
    end

    scenario 'cannot reqest quote with invalid data' do
        new_quote_form.visit_page.submit
        expect(page).to have_content("Must be selected")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Warden test helpers can be used with Devise and Capybara to shortcut logging here.  Here is the article in Devises wiki talking about it -
 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Comment: Include `include Warden::Test::Helpers` in spec/rails_helper.rb, then you can use `login_as` on your devise user, e.g. `login_as(user, :scope => :user)`